Python script to access Azure Service Bus with Managed identity
I want to send a message to a servicebus from Visual Studio Code, in a simple python script. I want to access the service bus using a managed identity (in this case my own user). From visual studio it would be fairly simple using the authentication part in options.
As I understand it in Visual Studio Code you can use the Azure Account extension. So I installed the extension, logged in with success and can see all azure ressources.
However when i run my python script I get following error:

Its like VS Code does not pickup my credentials. Beside logging into the extention is other configurations needed?

Please share your code in text format.

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.


Python script to access Azure Service Bus with Managed identity

It worked for me using below steps:
Firstly I logged in to azure using Azure CLI command:
az login


Then, I had set the subscription using below command:
 az account set --subscription  <subid>


Given below permission or role to my self in the resource:

Used below code which sent the message successfully:
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential as cho

rith_servicebus_name = "rith02.servicebus.windows.net"
q_name = "rith"
credential = cho()
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient(rith_servicebus_name , credential)
rith = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=q_name)
with rith:
    val = ServiceBusMessage("Hello Rithwik")
    rith.send_messages(val)

Output:

If the above process do not work, as an alternative you can use client id , tenant and secret as client credential login.
This issue comes when you do not set the account subscription or there is a issue with environment variables. Refer SO-Thread1 and SO-Thread2 for more information.

Thanks appreciated. I will give it a try.

I just tested worked perfectly. Thanks alot!

Glad it worked out for you @ThomasSegato
